# react-native keyboard auto hide issue

Tags: react-native, keyboard

Currently, I am developing a react-native app.  The problem is, when I touched text input box, the keyboard automatically hiding for first time only for every time relaunched my app.

My TextInput Component here:

```
<TextInput
  blurOnSubmit={false}
  placeholder={"Email..."}
  autoCapitalize="none"
  style={{
    height: 40,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    width: "90%",
  }}
  onChangeText={(email) => {
    this.setState({ email });
    this.validateEmail(email).then((res) => this.handleResponse(res));
  }}
  value={this.state.email}
  ref={(ref) => (this.email = ref)}
  onSubmitEditing={() => this.mobile.focus()}
/>
```

My Package.json dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.5.1",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-looped-carousel": "^0.1.13",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
  },
```

Comment: attach your codebase to this

Comment: @AkilaDevinda Dude,  I have uploaded my code.

Comment: @SkySakthi I'm facing the same problem. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @SkySakthi can you add full file code here?

Comment: @SoufianeOdf Still i did not found a propper solution.  But unfortunately,  i founded a different solution by myself.  Solution,  That problem occur only when we used this.props.navigation.navigate and this.props.navigation.push.  But,  if you used this.props.navigation.replace,  the auto hide issue solved.  I think this is community issue!.

Comment: @MuhammadNuman Hi dude,  My project was so big.  But, I have posted the reason of the issue,  if you still want my full code comment me.

Comment: @SkySakthi yeah! me too I figure out that this is a community issue. I have tried a solution, I replaced StackNavigator by NativeStackNavigator it solved the problem but it created another problems too, for example a couldn't make more than 1 level stack.

Comment: @SkySakthi I want only one file which can reproduce the issue on my side

Comment: @MuhammadNuman you don't need that, the problem is produced when you have the reactnavigation library in your project and you try to navigate to a view, and in that view, that you have navigated to, if you make a TextInput you will have this problem.

Comment: @SoufianeOdf Yes, you are right.  we need to wait for fix this issue from community.

Comment: Have you tried this - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#keyboardhandlingenabled

Comment: @AshwinMothilal Not yet bro,  But i don't known how i missed this.  I have seen that props,  But where don't known where to place it.  Like <NavigationContainer> or else?... Thank You.....

Comment: You need to send it as props for  "NavigatorName.Navigator".

Comment: @AshwinMothilal I have tried this before and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @SoufianeOdf what you're saying is
if you navigate to screen with input the problem appears
is that right?
for me the problem appears only for 1 client and the specific device

Answer (score 0):

Opps,  Unfortunately the React Native teams recently released new version of RN 0.63.0.  I migrated my project from version 0.62.2 to 0.63.0.  Then this issue gone.  So happy.
Thanks for RN developers for new release...

Comment: I just did the upgrade from 0.62.2 to 0.63.0 but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Try gradlew clean

Answer (score -2):

You can modify you AndroidManifes.xml like this below, this bugs is comes up within React Native above >59.

```
  <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
```

Then save, and run again your application project.

Comment: could you please explain in what way it is going to fix the problem?

Comment: The problem is Because in android manifest, yang like above in your manifest.

Comment: Please specify which setting exactly is supposed to fix the behaviour. We can not just copy over that entire file as most of these settings are not related and different on a per-app basis.